# Android: How to start the System Magnifier on click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, magnification

Is there a way to implement a magnifying glas within the html page via jQuery maby or within the android app? Best would be for a single picture?

In my app I display a html file out of my assets in a webview. The html page uses jQuery and a css file.

In that html page I show pictures and some of them have so many details that I need to magnify or zoom them.

The possibility to enable zooming in the webview is not good because I only want to enable zooming on single Pictures. Zooming the whole page results in the text being scrolled down or up.

I have tried several magnifying javascripts and one even worked on my computer but then I could not move the magnify-lens or glass or what it is called with my fingers on my phone.

Since I wasted a day on this problem without a workable solution, can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone? @Kailas , Thanks for the correction. But the question remains unanswered. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I just finished it myself :-) 
This page got me to do work it out. 
[Reasonable coding in for all I can say](http://cssdeck.com/labs/magnifying-glass-plugin-with-jquery-and-css3)

The magnifier reacts on clicks which is perfect for the use on a touch-phone. 
And one has just to link in one img and not a smal and a big version.... :-)